# Wireless keyboard signal deterioration

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Yesterday I have reinstalled windows, and my wireless ([Natural Wireless Ergonomic Keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-gb/d/natural-wireless-ergonomic-keyboard-7000)) started missing keystrokes and having delays. [I have followed instructions here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322609) (paired the device without much luck (pairing worked fine but keystrokes are still playing up), changed batteries, etc.).

**UPDATE:**

Same windows version, tried different USB slots, I am certain batteries are new, I have turned PC on the side for direct visibility between keyboard and receiver and its 2 feet away from keyboard ATM. It does work, but then every minute or so it stops for 2-3 seconds (sometimes 10-15) then works fine again or delays the keys pressed by a second or two.

Also [downloaded IntelyType](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/natural-wireless-ergonomic-keyboard-7000) driver but it says it's up to date.

Keyboard is quite old and it could be just a coincidence that it started dying  same time that I have reinstalled OS.

**Does signal deteriorate on old keyboards? How do I check what is causing this?**

Comment: Are you sure you just reinstalled Windows? From what you wrote you either changed versions of windows (and drivers installed are maybe faulty somehow) or you added either distance between keyboard and receiver or extra obstacles. I'd say you moved your receiver to another usb port (like from front to back of your desktop). I've worked with several keyboards, including 10-year old Logitech, and all of them still work fine. That or your new batteries are not new.

Comment: @AcePL Same windows version, tried different USB slots, I am certain batteries are new, I have turned PC on the side for direct visibility between keyboard and receiver and its 2 feet away from keyboard ATM. It does work, but then every minute or so it stops for 2-3 seconds (sometimes 10-15) then works fine again or delays the keys pressed by a second or two.

Comment: I will assume you have different drivers (different manufacturer, or a generic, or a different version) or a new conflict... Tricky to debug I'm afraid but to answer your question, yes, anything can deteriorate but it's hardware so *usually* it works or doesn't!

Comment: "Does signal deteriorate on old keyboards?" - Nope

Comment: Did you change anything else at the same time? E.g. did you add or enable wireless or bluetooth (both tend to use the 2.4GHz band, which is often also used for wireless keyboards).

Comment: @Hennes no new devices connected to PC. I am working in the office so it could be someones phone that is causing interference, however everyone was using them all the time anyway.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius - what kind of batteries: non-reusable alkaline or re-chargeable? I SO do recommend plain batteries, as rechargeables are tricky, especially when used in wireless sets. Also, your improved description of the issue points to driver. Definitely not the signal deterioration. Even if (not saying it is), 2 feet direct LOS is more than enough. Because, as Ramhound says and my experience confirms - signal does not deteriorate.

Comment: @AcePL Batteries are non-rechargeable Kodak from Poundland (opened new pack). Changed USB slot again - driver got reinstalled it seems to be working somewhat better, will try extension cable to put receiver under keyboard and see what it does.

Comment: Have plugged USB extension cable and now when receiver is under the keyboard it works no problem for 6 hours or so.